# How to check if Future[Seq[T]] is empty with specs2

Tags: scala, specs2

I tried to write some unit tests testing an asynchronous API using Specs2. According to the user guide, checking Futures should be easy by adding `.await` to your synchronous code. However, while this works for some things I've tested it doesn't work as expected for checking the length of sequences in the following example:

```
"A Seq" should {
  "be empty when nothing was added" in {
    Seq[String]() must have length(0) // compiles and runs correctly
    Seq[String]() must be empty       // compiles and runs correctly
  }
  "be empty when nothing was added async" in { implicit ee: ExecutionEnv =>
    Future{ Seq[String]() } must have.await length(0) // doesn't compile
    Future{ Seq[String]() } must be.await empty       // doesn't compile
    Future{ Seq[String]() } must have length(0).await // doesn't compile
    Future{ Seq[String]() } must be empty.await       // doesn't compile
  }
```

}

What's the idiomatic way to do this using Specs2?

Comment: I am not familiar with specs2 but while I was testing my code, I created await method myself and I was calling it on Future, not on some random matchers, and it seems like a reasonable solution to me. Maybe it's the case here. Maybe try `Future{ Seq[String]() }.await must be empty`

Comment: Try `must (be empty).await` and wrapping the conditional in parens. I'd answer but I don't have a specs2 project in front of me.

Answer (score 3):

There are limitations with both specs2 syntax and type inference here. You need to write the following:

```
 Future(Seq[String]()) must beEmpty[Seq[String]].await
```

Basically you can't use `await` with the `be + matcher` syntax and you have to annotate the `beEmpty` matcher.